# SQLAlchemy + alembic: create schema migration

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm not sure how to define a `create schema foo` migration? My Model looks like this (I'm using Flask-Migrate):

```
class MyTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "foo"}

    id = ColumnPrimKey()
    name = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

When I execute `mange db upgrade` I get a failure because the schema "foo" does not exist. How can I add a migration for the schema with SQLAlchemy and Alembic?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I accomplished this by modifying the migration `upgrade` command to first run:

```
op.execute("create schema foo")
```

And in the `downgrade` function

```
op.execute("drop schema foo")
```

So the whole migration file looks something like:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '6c82c972c61e'
down_revision = '553260b3e828'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.execute("create schema foo")
    ...

def downgrade():
    ...
    op.execute("drop schema foo")
```

Comment: Is there some way to make this work with `sqlalchemy.event`? For example, `event.listen(Base.metadata, "before_create", CreateSchema("foo"))`.

Comment: This solves the migration, but if you have another migration, it won't detect your schema again and will generate all the tables... That can be troublesome.  Is there a way to detect the changes in a different schema?

Comment: @Pstr You can specify the schema attribute on your metadata class either `metadata = Metadata(schema=<schema-name>)` or `Base = declarative_base(schema=<schema-name>)`

Comment: As an answer to my own question here, alembic will acknowledge the schemas if you set the argument   `include_schemas=True,` in the `context.configure()` function of the alembic/env.py file. Not sure why this setting is not on as default, though

Comment: I don't understand why `revision --autogenerate` doesn't detect and create these schemas. Is there some technical difficulty I'm not aware of? (The issue of where to put the `alembic_version` which dominates some of these conversations is a red herring to this discussion. This is about autogenerating schemas for tables to go into.)

Answer (score 3):

A potential issue with the accepted answer is that, for an initial migration, Alembic might have trouble finding a place to create the `alembic_version`. This is because because `op.execute("create schema foo")` is only executed *after* Alembic attempts to find its `alembic_version` table. The error pops up as:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema "foo" does not exist
```

The easy way out would be to have the `alembic_version` table live in another schema passing `version_table_schema` to `context.configure()` ([docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.version_table_schema)).

However, in many cases one might want to simultaneously (i) create a schema from scratch as part of an initial migration (e.g. to set up a testing environment) and (ii) have the `alembic_version` table in the target schema. In these cases, an alternative approach is to delegate the schema creation to `env.py`. Example:

```py
# env.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from bar import create_database_with_schema_if_not_exists

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ...
schema = "foo"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
create_database_with_schema_if_not_exists(engine, schema)
...
```

```py
# bar.py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists

def create_database_with_schema_if_not_exists(engine, schema):
    if not database_exists(engine.url):
        create_database(engine.url)
    if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, schema):
        engine.execute(sqlalchemy.schema.CreateSchema(schema))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add the following function to modify the MigrationScript directives in `env.py`:

```
from alembic import operations

def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
    """Modify the MigrationScript directives to create schemata as required.
    """
    script = directives[0]
    for schema in frozenset(i.schema for i in target_metadata.tables.values()):
        script.upgrade_ops.ops.insert(
            0, operations.ops.ExecuteSQLOp(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {schema}"))
        script.downgrade_ops.ops.append(
            operations.ops.ExecuteSQLOp(f"DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS {schema} RESTRICT"))
```

then add `process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives` in `context.configure`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `alembic_version` table is created inside the new schema none of the other approaches worked for me using `mssql+pyodbc` dialect.

This one does:

```
with context.begin_transaction():
    context.execute(
        f"""
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '{schema}')
        BEGIN 
          EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA {schema}') 
        END
        """
    )
    context.run_migrations()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which creates schemas automatically when they are first appearing in a migration (add this into env.py or at least import it from there):

```py
import logging
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any

import alembic
import sqlalchemy.sql.base
from alembic.autogenerate.api import AutogenContext
from alembic.operations.ops import (
    CreateTableOp,
    ExecuteSQLOp,
    UpgradeOps,
)

_logger = logging.getLogger(f"alembic.{__name__}")


class ExecuteArbitraryDDLOp(ExecuteSQLOp):
    def __init__(
        self,
        ddl: sqlalchemy.sql.base.Executable | str,
        reverse_ddl: sqlalchemy.sql.base.Executable | str,
        *,
        execution_options: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        """A DDL Operation with both upgrade and downgrade commands."""
        super().__init__(ddl, execution_options=execution_options)
        self.reverse_ddl = reverse_ddl

    def reverse(self) -> "ExecuteArbitraryDDLOp":
        """Return the reverse of this ExecuteArbitraryDDLOp (used for downgrades)."""
        return ExecuteArbitraryDDLOp(
            ddl=self.reverse_ddl, reverse_ddl=self.sqltext, execution_options=self.execution_options
        )


@alembic.autogenerate.comparators.dispatch_for("schema")
def create_missing_schemas(
    autogen_context: AutogenContext, upgrade_ops: UpgradeOps, schema_names: Iterable[str | None]
) -> None:
    """Creates missing schemas.

    This depends on sqla/alembic to give us all existing
    schemas in the schema_names argument.
    """
    used_schemas = set()
    for operations_group in upgrade_ops.ops:
        # We only care about Tables at the top level, so this is enough for us.
        if isinstance(operations_group, CreateTableOp) and operations_group.schema:
            used_schemas.add(operations_group.schema)

    existing_schemas = set(schema_names)
    missing_schemas = used_schemas - existing_schemas
    if missing_schemas:
        for schema in missing_schemas:
            _logger.info("Add migration ops for schema: %s", schema)
            upgrade_ops.ops.insert(
                0,
                ExecuteArbitraryDDLOp(
                    ddl=f"CREATE SCHEMA {schema}",
                    reverse_ddl=f"DROP SCHEMA {schema}",
                ),
            )
```

Source: https://www.katzien.de/en/posts/2023-11-16-create-missing-schemas-in-alembic/ (disclaimer: my own blog)